# L'Hopitals Rule and division by zero?

Tags: calculus

My question concerns division by zero. Let's say there are two functions, $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ that approach $0$, as $x\to t$, also assume their derivative w.r.t. $x$ is finite as $x\to t$. Using L'Hopital's Rule: $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ $x\to t$, Can you say $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$? Or $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} - \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} = 0$? To be more specific is $\frac{1}{0} = \frac{1}{0}$? Or is it undefined?

Answer (score 2):

When you talk of $f(x)/g(x)$ then you assume that $g(x) \neq 0$ as $x \to t$. At the same time you assume that $f(x) \to 0, g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to t$. This is the typical use-case where L'Hopital's Rule can be applied provided $f'(x)/g'(x)$ tends to a limit as $x \to t$.

Now note that if $f'(x)/g'(x) \to L$ as $x \to t$ then it is also obvious that $g'(x) \neq 0$ as $x \to t$. The L'Hopital's Rule says that under these conditions $f(x)/g(x) \to L$ as $x \to t$. This means that $$\lim_{x to t}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to t}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\text{  or what is the same as  }\lim_{x \to t}\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\right) = 0\tag{1}$$ but **this does not mean that** $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$ Note further that *if two functions have same limit as $x \to t$ then it does not necessarily mean that they are equal as $x \to t$*.

The symbols like $1/0$ don't mean anything and it is better not to worry about them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27270/discussion-on-answer-by-paramanand-singh-lhopitals-rule-and-division-by-zero).

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer. For some reason MSE was not giving me a link to move the discussion to a chat window. I don't know why that did not happen automatically. In the past I have seen that MSE detects extended discussion in comments and suggests by itself to move it to a chat room.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot say any of those things. Division by $0$ is **ALWAYS** undefined (in the real numbers before anyone says anything).

Comment: Sorry about that. New to this but I should have realized.

Comment: Does that mean that division by zero means something in the complex numbers?

Comment: x can be complex and Dodo's answer will still be the same, zerosoftheta. But I shouldn't speak for Dodo.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably, $\frac10$ can take on any or no value. Therefore it is incorrect, though this may seem strange, to say that $\frac10=\frac10$ in any (real) case. Of course, any value *approaching* zero but not zero can be compared.

**Edit:** In any other real case, $\frac1x=\frac1x$, because values only have a single reciprocal.

Comment: 1/x = 1/x as x->0?

Comment: Yes, as long as x does not reach zero.

Comment: @fred-simpleton So 1/x = 1/x in all real cases, except for x = 0 and x = 0 only, where it is undefined.

Comment: Thank you, you have answered my question. You don't know what this does for me.  You see I have a proof concerning the Riemann Zeta function that would be significant if not already found.  Simple proof.

Comment: @fred-simpleton Glad to hear that answers your question. Could you tick it as the answer?

Comment: I can't. I'm a guest.